# Monitoring Azure WebJobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

How can I monitor azure web jobs when their last run result is failed or if a continuous web job is not running?

I have found cloudmonix which does work. Are there any other products out there?

Zapier only has a zap for triggered web jobs not running continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know of any other products other than [CloudMonix](http://cloudmonix.com) that can monitor your Webjobs, but if all you need is alerts when a job fails, you can probably write a console program yourself that checks against your Webjobs with Azure Management certificate.

Look into IWebSiteExtensionsClient and its TriggeredWebJobs or ContinuousWebJobs properties within the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites package.

Answer (score 13):

In case someone else has the same question, there is a way you can monitor Web Jobs with App Insights Web Tests.

What you need to do is to use the Kudu Web Jobs API to get the current status of the web job, e.g.

For triggered web jobs: 
https://{webapp-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/{webjob-name}/

For continuous web jobs: 
https://{webapp-name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuousjobs/{webjob-name}/

And call the Kudu API from your App Insights Web Tests. You can configure your web tests to include the required Authorization header and to validate the JSON response. You can do this by adding multi-steps web tests.

Multi-steps web tests can be created using Visual Studio Enterprise or Ultimate, or by editing the web test xml definition directly.

You can find more details here:

https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/08/11/monitoring-azure-web-jobs-health-with-application-insights/

HTH

Comment: Thanks Paco. This sounds like a good approach. 
Why is it downvoted?

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I believe some didn't like that I didn't post the whole solution here and referred a blog post. I hope you find the reference useful. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Thanks Paco. This answer is very useful for me but I faced some issue like whenever continuous web job stopped then only I send the alert email to my development team. For that I added this line   <RuleParameter Name="FindText" Value="&quot;status&quot;:&quot;(Stopped)&quot;" /> in web test xml definition. Can you please tell how to configure the alert in web test definition to send mail along with status of the web job?

Comment: Hi @pradeep, in the WebTest you configure the expected response, so you might want to configure it as <RuleParameter Name="FindText" Value="&quot;status&quot;:&quot;Running&quot;" /> so you receive an alert whenever the status is not Running.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get the success alert on every 1 hour, if web job running.

Comment: If you want to be notified when the Web Job is not Stopped, i.e. Running, you should configure it as:
<RuleParameters>
 <RuleParameter Name="FindText" Value="&quot;status&quot;:&quot;Stopped&quot;" />
 <RuleParameter Name="IgnoreCase" Value="True" />
 <RuleParameter Name="UseRegularExpression" Value="False" />
 <RuleParameter Name="PassIfTextFound" Value="True" />
</RuleParameters>

Comment: I already tried with the above lines of code. Only thing is whenever web job running I got the mail, but in that I am able to see like it's warning message. Because the web test fails in one or more locations. But I want the alert mail with success message.

Comment: App Insights Alerts are designed to raise alerts on unexpected statuses. For sending emails whenever your WebJob is running as expected, you would need a different approach. E.g. a recurring LogicApp which calls the KuduApi, checks the status and sends an email.