# How to intercept an Azure WebJob failure / exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-application-insights

Currently in Azure when a a WebJob throws an exception, the exception gets caught and handled by the `JobHost` (somehow) and then logs the exception to the dashboard that's available through the blade of the Web App in which the webjob is hosted. Is there any way to intercept the error handling or override it so that I can plug in my Application Insights instance ?

Comment: Check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798640/monitoring-azure-webjobs

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Azure WebJobs SDK Extensions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#errortrigger) : there is an `ErrorTrigger` so that you can use to intercept unhandled exceptions :

```
public class UnhandledErrorTrigger : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

    public UnhandledErrorTrigger(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
    {
        _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    }              

    public void UnHandledException([ErrorTrigger("0:01:00", 1)] TraceFilter filter, TextWriter log)
    {
        foreach (var traceEvent in filter.Events)
        {
            _telemetryClient.TrackException(traceEvent.Exception);
        }

        // log the last detailed errors to the Dashboard
        log.WriteLine(filter.GetDetailedMessage(1));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _telemetryClient.Flush();
    }
}
```

To register the Error extensions, call `config.UseCore()` in your startup code :

```
private static void Main()
{
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
    config.UseCore();

    ...
    new JobHost(config).RunAndBlock();
}
```

So if you are using an IoC container, you can easily inject your TelemetryClient. To configure a job activator for the webjob you can look at this post:

- [Dependency injection using Azure WebJobs SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34146460/4167200)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at some azure docs [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-desktop/). You can attach a handler to the `AppDomain` handling unknown exceptions (taken from the link above):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException; 

// ... 

private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) 
{ 
    ExceptionTelemetry excTelemetry = new ExceptionTelemetry((Exception)e.ExceptionObject); 
    excTelemetry.SeverityLevel = SeverityLevel.Critical; 
    excTelemetry.HandledAt = ExceptionHandledAt.Unhandled; 

    telemetryClient.TrackException(excTelemetry); 

    telemetryClient.Flush(); 
}
```

Comment: Actually I found something similar in the documents for Raygun. The problem with this approach is that I can't guarantee any metrics or extra properties I've built up during the job get recorded unless I build in some very messy exception handling for every possible throw statement. If I'm going to our that kind of logic in, I might as well just instrument the job methods directly

Comment: hmmm... I'm currently thinking of some dictionary to store key/value pairs which can be stored in a global property that can be used to store the information to be passed to AI.

Comment: @AlexMarshall do you a DI Container in your webjob?

Comment: Yes, I do. We're currently using Ninject

Comment: @AlexMarshall, I've added an answer about ErrorTrigger